# I keep getting a mutating table error

Tags: plsql

I am wanting to output the OLD and New salary values for every row but keep getting a mutating table error.

Here is my trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER print_salary_changes
AFTER UPDATE OF salary ON emp2
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
v_employee_id  NUMBER;
v_old_salary  NUMBER;
v_new_salary  NUMBER;
v_difference  NUMBER;
BEGIN 
SELECT :OLD.employee_id, :OLD.salary, :NEW.salary INTO v_employee_id, v_old_salary,       v_new_salary FROM emp2;
v_difference := v_old_salary - v_new_salary;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('employee_id: ' || v_employee_id);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('old salary: ' || v_old_salary );
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('new salary: ' || v_new_salary);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('DIFFERENCE: ' || v_difference);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to execute the select statement, your trigger will already have the old and new values.

Try it this way:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER print_salary_changes
    AFTER UPDATE OF salary ON emp2
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('employee_id: ' || :OLD.employee_id);
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('old salary: ' || :OLD.salary );
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('new salary: ' || :NEW.salary);
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('DIFFERENCE: ' || (:OLD.salary -:NEW.salary ));
END;
```

Comment: The calculation of `v_difference` should be removed as it will always be NULL (no value has been assigned to either `v_old_salary` or `v_new_salary`.

Comment: true, even more, none of the variables where needed anymore. Edited my response.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected and normal behavior, Oracle wants to protect you:

- each statement is atomic
- each statement sees a consistent view of the data
  Transform you trigger into procedure to solve the logic of your action.
  **or**
  *Use autonomous transactions* 
  You can avoid the mutating table error by marking your trigger as an autonomous transaction, making it independent from the table that calls the procedure.